# How to solder USB-A female socket to PCB?

Tags: pcb-assembly

Sorry I have tried many google searches but can't find anything directly relevant.

A USB Type-A female socket, through-hole, right-angle PCB mount has small 45-degree bent pins for soldering the shield to PCB. What should be done with these pins? Should they be pushed through a hole and bent over on the other side? Why are they bent to start with?

[image]

From: 
https://nz.element14.com/wurth-elektronik/61400416021/usb-2-0-type-a-receptacle-tht/dp/1642033?st=usb%20a%20socket

Comment: they can be wrapped around the edges of a narrow board

Comment: OK, but is that what they are *designed* for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are extra pins for reducing stress when you unplug or plug in the cable or whatever into the connector. This will ensure you don't break your solder joins on the pin.

Normally you would solder them to the PCB.

Edit 1:

As @Justme suggested, have look in the datasheet. The two 2.3 holes are for the extra pins.

[image]

They will just snap in place when you, like you said, press fit the connector on the PCB.

The shape is that the connector clips in place when you put in the through holes. They are "spring loaded" and will hold the connector tied. If you follow the footprint in the datasheet you don't need to bend anything. Just clip the connector in place and solder all pins of the connector.

Comment: I realise their purpose and that they are to be soldered. But, I'm not clear how to fit them into a PCB when they are such an odd shape. I'm sorry I don't understand your final sentence.

Comment: Updated answer...

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

If you click your link and then click open the datasheet you see the PCB footprint that it is supposed to be mounted on. Those bent leads go to holes and they grip quite tightly and keep the stress away from the actual contact pins. Also keeps connector firmly in place before soldering.